# Restoring MYSQL User Accounts to new Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to combine two MYSQL Database installations into a single installation. I have already used a batch script to export each individual database to SQL files so they can be imported into the MYSQL that is being kept.

The problem is each individual database has a unique user assigned to it which also needs to be brought over. When doing this in the past, I imported the "mysql" database along with the result, and this caused corruption.

What is the best way to export ONLY the users from the "mysql" database and import them into a a different MySQL instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--no-create-info` option to `mysqldump` to keep it from dropping the old table on the target server.

If you have any overlap in the usernames on the two installations, use the `--ignore` option so that they will be ignored when merging.

So the command is:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --ignore mysql user > user.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are USING SQL yog then,

```
go to the TABLE which you need to export to other host/database
right click on the TABLE 
SELECT copy TABLE TO different HOST/Database
```

Hope it is helpful